# Nexus 7 - mysterious blank search screen when orientation change

Tags: android

When finishing an activity (landscape), going back to another activity (portrait), the below screen appears. Why?  There is no error message.

[image: mysterious search screen]

Answer (score 0):

Add this : `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` to the Activity inside your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: No, I don't have clean code at this moment, but I have tested it with 3 different activities - this happens only when there is the orientation change.

Comment: This is just for debugging purposes. Override the `onConfigurationChanged` method inside any one of Activity and check the log cat to determine what's happening when the orientation changes. From that u can then decide what to do.

Comment: I just did, in debugging mode the search screen does not appear. Those which change inside the Configuration object are: compatScreenHeightDp, compatScreenWidthDp, locale (id, not values), orientation, screenHeightDp, screenWidthDp, seq